# TypeError JavaScript Audio File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have built my custom music player, which uses some of my custom made formulas to calculate track duration and all. You can see the NaN error.
Sorry for low quality gif.

[image]

It is made in javascript, I want to share it with the open source community by making it into a plugin or so, and doesn't present any apparent issues, except an annoying error every time you play a song.

TypeError - Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided double value is non-finite.

```
const myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudioElement'); //audio HTML5 element
const mySongNames = ['Týr - Ormurin Langi'.....];
const mySongFiles = ['audio0.mp3', 'audio1.mp3', 'audio2.mp3', 'audio3.mp3', 'audio4.mp3', 'audio5.mp3', 'audio6.mp3'];
const mySongLyrics = [....
];
const amountOfSongs = mySongNames.length - 1;
var playPauseCounter = 0; //determines if we play or pause
var songCounter = 0; //current song
var gradCounter = 0;

$('#player-background').css('padding', '12px');

function enableGradient() {
    $('#myPlayer').css('padding', '');
    $('#myPlayer').css('background', '');
    $('#player-background').addClass('gradient');
}

function disableGradient() {
    $('#player-background').removeClass('gradient');
    $('#player-background').attr('style', '');
    if (Cookies.get('mode') == 'light') {
        $('#player-background').css('padding', '12px');
        $('#myPlayer').css('background', '#FFF');
    } else {
        $('#player-background').css('padding', '12px');
        $('#myPlayer').css('background', '#000');
    }
}

$('#toggleImages').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#cbx').trigger('click');
});
$('#cbx').click(function() {
    if (gradCounter == 0 || gradCounter % 2 === 0) {
        enableGradient();
        gradCounter++;
    } else {
        disableGradient();
        gradCounter++;
    }
});

//here we deal with every second passed
//and update times accordingly
$('#myAudioElement').on('timeupdate', function() {
    //current time elapsed
    var currentMins = parseInt(Math.floor(myAudio.currentTime / 60));
    //total length of the song
    var totalMins = parseInt(Math.floor(myAudio.duration / 60));
    //number of seconds in current time
    var currentRest = parseInt(Math.floor(myAudio.currentTime - currentMins * 60));
    //number of seconds in total time
    var totalRest = parseInt(Math.floor(myAudio.duration - totalMins * 60));
    //set current time text
    $('#currentTime').text(`${currentMins} m ${(currentRest)} s`);
    //set total time text
    $('#totalTime').text(`${totalMins} m ${totalRest} s`);
    //width of the bar according to progress
    $('#myRange').val(myAudio.currentTime * 100 / myAudio.duration);
});
//deal with music ending
$('#myAudioElement').on('ended', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //if last song in playlist ended go to beggining
    if (songCounter == amountOfSongs) {
        songCounter = 0;
        myAudio.src = `music/${mySongFiles[songCounter]}`;
        myAudio.currentTime = 0;
        playAudio();
    } else if (songCounter < amountOfSongs) {
        songCounter++;
        myAudio.src = `music/${mySongFiles[songCounter]}`;
        myAudio.currentTime = 0;
        playAudio();
    }
});

function playAudio() {
    console.log('Attempting to play audio!');
    $('#myAudioElement').trigger('play');
    $('#title').text(mySongNames[songCounter]);
    $('#linkToLyrics').attr('href', mySongLyrics[songCounter]);
}

function pauseAudio() {
    console.log('Attempting to pause audio!');
    $('#myAudioElement').trigger('pause');
    $('#title').text(mySongNames[songCounter]);
    $('#linkToLyrics').attr('href', mySongLyrics[songCounter]);

}
//set volume according to input
$(document).on('input', '#myVolume', function() {
    $('#slider_value').html(parseInt($(this).val()));
    myAudio.volume = parseInt($(this).val()) / 100;
});
//set time in track according to input
$(document).on('input', '#myRange', function() {
    $('#slider_value').html(parseInt($(this).val()));
    myAudio.currentTime = (myAudio.duration * (parseInt($(this).val()) / 100));
});
//max volume
$('#volumeup').click(function() {
    $('#myVolume').val(100);
    myAudio.volume = 1;
});
//min volume
$('#volumedown').click(function() {
    $('#myVolume').val(0);
    myAudio.volume = 0;
});
//previous track
$('#back').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //if its still first track, go back to the last
    if (songCounter == 0) {
        songCounter = amountOfSongs;
        myAudio.src = `music/${mySongFiles[songCounter]}`;
        myAudio.currentTime = 0;
        playAudio();
        $('#playpause').removeClass('fas');
        $('#playpause').removeClass('fa-play');
        $('#playpause').addClass('fas');
        $('#playpause').addClass('fa-pause');
        playPauseCounter++;
        console.log(`Now Playing ${mySongFiles[songCounter]} with counter = ${songCounter}`);
    } else if (songCounter > 0) {
        songCounter--;
        myAudio.currentTime = 0;
        myAudio.src = `music/${mySongFiles[songCounter]}`;
        playAudio();
        $('#playpause').removeClass('fas');
        $('#playpause').removeClass('fa-play');
        $('#playpause').addClass('fas');
        $('#playpause').addClass('fa-pause');
        playPauseCounter++;
        console.log(`Now Playing ${mySongFiles[songCounter]} with counter = ${songCounter}`);
    }
});
//next track
$('#next').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (songCounter == amountOfSongs) {
        songCounter = 0;
        myAudio.src = `music/${mySongFiles[songCounter]}`;
        myAudio.currentTime = 0;
        playAudio();
        $('#playpause').removeClass('fas');
        $('#playpause').removeClass('fa-play');
        $('#playpause').addClass('fas');
        $('#playpause').addClass('fa-pause');
        console.log(`Now Playing ${mySongFiles[songCounter]} with counter = ${songCounter}`);
    } else if (songCounter < amountOfSongs) {
        songCounter++;
        myAudio.src = `music/${mySongFiles[songCounter]}`;
        myAudio.currentTime = 0;
        playAudio();
        $('#playpause').removeClass('fas');
        $('#playpause').removeClass('fa-play');
        $('#playpause').addClass('fas');
        $('#playpause').addClass('fa-pause');
        console.log(`Now Playing ${mySongFiles[songCounter]} with counter = ${songCounter}`);
    }
});
//play and pause, change icon too
$('#playpause').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (playPauseCounter === 0 || playPauseCounter % 2 === 0) {
        myAudio.src = `music/${mySongFiles[songCounter]}`;
        $('#playpause').removeClass('fas');
        $('#playpause').removeClass('fa-play');
        $('#playpause').addClass('fas');
        $('#playpause').addClass('fa-pause');
        playAudio();
    } else if (playPauseCounter === 1 || playPauseCounter % 2 === 1) {
        $('#playpause').removeClass('fas');
        $('#playpause').removeClass('fa-pause');
        $('#playpause').addClass('fas');
        $('#playpause').addClass('fa-play');
        pauseAudio();
    }
    playPauseCounter++;
});
```

Comment: This is going to be very hard to debug without a fully working example of the problem.

Comment: What is the value of `$(this).val()` in `on('input')` function ? is it a number ?

Comment: jjba.ddnsking.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever taking input like $(this).val() if it is an integer make

```
parseInt($(this).val());
```

So you can avoid NaN error.

Edit: Just Like Below:

```
myAudio.volume = parseInt($(this).val()) / 100;
});

$(document).on('input', '#myRange', function() {
  $('#slider_value').html($(this).val());
  myAudio.currentTime = (myAudio.duration * (parseInt($(this).val()) / 100));
});

$('#volumeup').click(function(){
  $('#myVolume').val(100);
  myAudio.volume = 1;
```

Comment: please see the edit.. I applied the suggestion and now the error only appears very very briefly and disappears, already good enough for me, but I will love any suggestion! Thanks for your wisdom kind sir @Sindhoor

Comment: even while doing Math.floor() that will return int value so no need to parse int again. but inside, myAudio.duration, myAudio.currentTime etc dont know exactly whether it is int or integer in string format. so better parse it before calculation. like: Math.floor(parseInt(myAudio.currentTime) - currentMins * 60) . that may help.

Comment: and one more: int doesn't require === comparision.

you can change " if (gradCounter == 0 || gradCounter % 2 === 0) " 
to " if (gradCounter == 0 || gradCounter % 2 == 0) "

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! the NaN only now occurs until the music is loaded, which is totally fine and logical. Basically 20 microseconds or so, thanks to your advices, the code is much safer and fail proof. Merry Xmas to everyone, specially you sir!